# How to implement floating button in react-native that sticks to the screen at some point of scrolling?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I managed to implement floating button by defining button outside of ScrollView, using `position: 'absolute'` and `bottom: 20`.

Now I need this button to stick to the screen when I pass some point during scrolling.

I don't want it to always float, at some point I want it to stick to the screen. How could I achieve this effect? I saw that in one of the mobile apps and really liked it.

Comment: you want to hide and show on scrolling right?

Comment: You could still use position: absolute, calculate the height of the text using onLayout, and place the button according to the layout. Lmk if you need an example.

Comment: @Abe yes, I need an example, if you have, thanks

Comment: @AlokSingh this way might also work, could you please provide an example in the answer?